# Why does the vertical scroll appear on iOS browsers when the momentum scroll is enabled?

Tags: html, css, ios, browser, scroll

I'm trying to create a simple carousel with horizontal scroll with using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` and  `overflow-x: auto`. Here is source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-tu-xxfz0?file=/index.html:333-350

This works perfect for me everywhere, except iOS devices. But vertical scroll appears on iOS browsers. Here is the video: https://youtu.be/BNugrdxX9MU

I know that i can fix it by setting `overflow-y: hidden` on carousel container or on element container. But this solution doesn't suit me, because i need to show some content outside the element or container with absolute positioning.

It looks like as an iOS bug. Are there any ideas how to fix it?